# Prove that the language { uw : |u| =2 |w| } is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have a problem with this following question:

> Prove that the language $\{uw : |u|=2|w|\}$ is regular.

I tried to give this regular expression $(uw²)^*$ to resolve it.

Comment: As written, the language is *not* regular.  Have you made a typo?  Also, your proposed regex would accept `uwwuwwuwwuww`.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried towards proving your claim? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: @Smsarr The language definition leaves out that $u,w \in \Sigma^*$ for some alphabet $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string of the form $uw$ where $|u| = 2|w|$ is a string whose length is a multiple of $3$. We are therefore considering the language of strings over some alphabet $\Sigma = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_k \}$ (not specified in the question). whose length is a multiple of $3$. Let $\Sigma$ be the regular expression $a_1 + \cdots + a_k$. Then a regular expression descring the language in question is

$$(\Sigma\Sigma\Sigma)^*$$

Comment: Can we draw an automat modulo 3

Answer (score 1):

$r = (000 + 001 + 010 + 011 + 100 + 101 + 110 + 111)^*$

Update:

**Proof**:
Without loss of generality assume that our alphabet is $\{0,1\}$.
Then $uw$ consists of 0 and 1. Any string of 0 and 1s may by written as a concatenation of two strings $u$ and $w$. For example 
$010101110$ may be written as a concatenation of $u=010101$ and $w=110$. But the problem says that the length of $u$ must be two times of that of $w$, which has nothing to do with the symbols of $u$ and $w$. In other words the condition does not stipulate anything regarding the content of the strings. The string $uw$ may be any string of 0 and 1s providing **it can be written as a concatenation of two strings $u$ and $w$** with length $|w|$ and $|u|=2|w|$. So, the string $uw$ has always length $|w| + 2|w| = 3|w|$, meaning that all strings in this language has lengths multiple of 3. Hence, any string of length 3k can be split up into $k$ substrings of length 3, that is one of $000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110,111$. 
QED

---

Example 1: $0101110 \notin L$ because its length is not multiple of 3.

Example 2: $010111000 \in L$ because its length is multiple of 3. We can take $w = 000$ and $u = 010111$.

Comment: $r =$ ... 0 to 7?

Comment: Raphael, proof added, Ben. I, they are simply all strings of length 3 of 0 and 1s. You would have 27 strings if you had 3 letter alphabet.